# Checking to see if multiple conditions are true within a group in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, predicate

Lets say I have the following table depicting a one-many relationship

```
col1  |  col2
------------- 
1     |  foo
1     |  bar
2     |  foo
3     |  buzz
```

**I need to group by `col1` and I need a boolean indicating whether or not there is *both* a mapping to 'foo' *and* a mapping to 'bar'.**

So, the final result set would be

```
col1 | foobar
-------------
1    |  1
2    |  0
3    |  0
```

What is the best way to achieve this in T-SQL?

I've been trying something roughly equivalent to the following query with no luck.

```
SELECT

  col1

  , (
    MAX (
      CASE WHEN
        COL2 = 'foo'
      THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END) = 1
    AND
    MAX (
      CASE WHEN
        COL2 = 'bar'
      THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END) = 1
  )           
FROM 
  table
GROUP BY 
  col1
```

---

**EDIT:**

To clarify, this table is a simplification.

I am looking for a solution to the general problem of having a one-many mapping and needing to produce a new 1-1 mapping with a Boolean indicating if a variable number of predicates are true of the different elements in the groups in the co-domain. (grouped by the fact that the same element maps to them)

Also, I should clarify that these various predicates could be anything.

For example, maybe I want to see if at least one of the columns in one of the rows = 'foo' and also that a different column in a (possibly different) row within the same group is between a certain set of numeric values.

Comment: Don't use `AND`. That is a bitwise operation in the context of that expression. Just say addition and a single equality: `MAX(CASE...THEN 1...) + MAX(CASE...THEN 1...) = 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

#### EDIT: Better use `COUNT(DISTINCT col2)`

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col1 INT,col2 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'foo')
,(1,'bar')
,(2,'foo')
,(3,'buzz');

SELECT col1
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT col2)-1
FROM @tbl
GROUP BY col1
```

### UPDATE:

If you try it like this, you would even see, which values are there. If you are only interested in "one or many" you might check for a comma in the returned string:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col1 INT,col2 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'foo')
,(1,'bar')
,(2,'foo')
,(3,'buzz');

SELECT outerTbl.col1
      ,STUFF
      (
          (
          SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + col2 
          FROM @tbl AS innerTbl
          WHERE innerTbl.col1=outerTbl.col1
          FOR XML PATH('')
          ),1,2,''
      )
FROM @tbl AS outerTbl
GROUP BY outerTbl.col1
```

This is the result:

```
1   bar, foo
2   foo
3   buzz
```

Comment: This happens to work for the sample table I provided. But my sample is a drastic oversimplification only meant to communicate my question (which I have now emboldened). In reality, the table may be much larger and the value '1'  in col 1 might mapp to various, other values as well.

Comment: please see my newest question edits. I apologize I should have been more specific about the grain of the actual problem I was looking to solve.

Comment: @LukeP OK, I've read your edits... Why not just check for `theCombinedColumn LIKE '%foo%' AND theCombinedColumn LIKE '%bar%' AND SomeNumeric BETWEEN 0 AND 10`?

Comment: I'm pretty new to sql. What do you mean by `theCombinedColumn`? you're checking it against 2 distinct values, so I would think that predicate would always be false, right? Could you extrapolate that snippet into a full query so i could see more clearly?

Comment: @LukeP, oh, this is just the column I return containing "bar, foo" or just "foo" or "buzz"... All values bound to this relation would appear as distinct list...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple option

```
select  col1
        ,MAX(case when col2='foo' then 1 else 0 end)*MAX(case when col2='bar' then 1 else 0 end) foobar
from    @tbl
group by col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
  col1,
  case when foo > 0 and bar > 0 then true else false end foobar
from (
  select
    col1,
    sum(case when col2 = 'foo' then 1 end) foo,
    sum(case when col2 = 'bar' then 1 end) bar
  from table
  group by col1) x
```